# Analyzing Multiply imputed datasets rich in categorical data

Tags: r, categorical-data, multiple-imputation, pooling, mice

My original dataset with 48 subjects has a considerable number of missing items. Majority of the data is categorical (dichotomous) and some of it is ranked (ordinal). I performed a multiple imputation using MICE in R. I am interested in running the following tests: Fisher exact test for relationship between two variables, mcnemars test for paired proportions, Wilcoxon signed rank test and the sign test. My problem is that after running these tests I am unable to pool the results from each of the five imputed datasets to come up with a single report-able result. I mean I cannot get a pooled P-value, pooled OR, pooled median. I also cannot get a pooled proportion estimate of any of the dichotomous variables. Corresponding 95% CI for each of the above estimates cannot be computed as well.

Is there a way to combine these results using Rubin's rules in R?

Comment: Are you asking a statistical question - is it technically possible - or a programming question - how do I do it in R? If the latter you would be better off on and R specific site like R-help or perhaps a programming site like StackOverflow

Comment: I need answers for both. Statistically because I have not come across any solid literature that supports pooling of p values, effect and effect sizes from multiply imputed datasets. So is it technically possible? If possible please share any relevant literature. Thanks.

Comment: I have it figured out. The pool.scalar function pools results for proportions and numerical estimates which solves part of my problem. Rubin's rules direct that a simple average of the estimates (effects and p-values) is enough to summarize results of any tests from the five imputed datasets. In addition the variance of the estimates should be computed to give a picture of the variability of the results due to missingness of data. I will do this manually.